# Compiling LAMP from source - apache2 error “no MPM package installed”

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server, lamp

I've compiled LAMP from source on a Ubuntu VPS. I had to remove a previously installed version of Apache then I manually compiled all the packages, which seems to have worked up unto a point - however, when I try to run commands like "/etc/init.d/apache2 restart" I get the following error - No apache MPM package installed. I have installed mpm-prefork so I don't know why i'm getting this problem. My configure command is as follows:

./configure --enable-so --enable-modules=most --with-mpm=prefork

I have deliberately not used apt-get to install anything and want to avoid this if possible.

Anyone have any guidance on how to resolve this error? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that /etc/init.d/apache2 belongs to the Ubuntu package (check with "dpkg -S /etc/init.d/apache2") and it is of course not aware of your own setup of Apache.

Since you did not mention the --prefix= switch in your call to ./configure, I assume that your installation ("make install") of Apache ended up somewhere under /usr/local/ which is of course a location nowhere compatible with the Ubuntu Sys-V-Init script /etc/init.d/apache2.

Since all this stuff leaves me with the impression that you are not that familiar with Linux/Unix and especially Apache I would like to advise you to use the prepackaged versions of Apache, provided by your Distribution (Ubuntu) if you are planning to use this server in a production environment.

If you just plan on learning the internals of Apache, try to take a look inside /etc/init.d/apache2. It's just a shell script and maybe you can adopt the paths to fit you own installation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fladi. Yes, that all makes perfect sense. This is not a production server, it's a development server which i'm setting up as an exercise to help improve my understanding of linux and I also specifically need to configure PHP 5.1.6 with Apache2, which requires a manual setup as far as i can see. Running /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl restart works for me, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Have a Look at
http://www.lamphowto.com/

They provide the complete tutorial for installing LAMP Server in a PC. 
Of course it would vary with distributions. But this will help you nevertheless